# Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00000000000a0000

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, att

After calling a function `setup_ivt`, got an error:
`Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00000000000a0000`

x86 real mode program, starts from boot loader which reads in the following sectors into memory (put the read in sectors from `0x7E00`, just after where boot sector sits).

Just after the label `main`, error happens if using the `call setup_ivt`.
Program works normally if put the function body of `setup_ivt` directly there instead of using `call`. 
Anything wrong there with the `ret`? Thanks Michael.

```
.code16               #! tell the assembler to generate 16-bit code
.globl _start           
.section .text
_start:
    cli
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es
    mov %ax, %fs
    mov %ax, %gs
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $_start, %sp
    sti
    cld
load_to_RAM_from_2nd_Sector:
    mov $0x00, %edx   # see section: Int 13/AH=02h - DISK - READ SECTOR(S) INTO MEMORY
    mov $0x02, %ecx
    mov $0x7E0, %ax   # Read in the 2nd sector from disk to memory 0x7E00
    mov %ax, %es        
    xor %bx, %bx
    movb $0x02, %ah
    movb SYSLEN, %al
    int $0x13
    jnc ok_load
die:jmp die

ok_load:
    cli
    mov $0x7E0, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $0x1000, %cx
    xor %esi, %esi
    xor %edi, %edi
    rep movsw
    sti
    ljmp *head_offset

# data region
SYSLEN: .word 0x11      # less than 17 sector of program head
head_segment:.word 0x0
head_offset: .word 0x7E00

.org 510
.word 0xAA55            # last 16 bits of first 512 bytes on disk

Second_Sector: 
    cli                 # Turn off interrupts
    xor %ax, %ax        # Initialize the segments, set the stack to grow down from
    mov %ax, %ds        # start of bootloader at _start. SS:SP=0x0000:0x7c00
    mov %ax, %es
    mov %ax, %fs
    mov %ax, %gs
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0x7C00, %sp
    cld                 # Set direction flag forward for string instructions
main: # main program starts
    call setup_ivt
#    pushl %eax
#    pushl %edx
#    pushw %es
#    movl  $0, %edx
#    movl  $0, %eax
#    movw  %ax, %es
#    lea   ignore_int, %ax
#loop_ivt:  
#    movl  %eax, %es:(,%edx,4)
#    addl  $1, %edx
#    cmpl  $256, %edx
#    jb    loop_ivt
#    popw  %es
#    popl  %edx
#    popl  %eax
#jmp .
    movl $system_interrupt, %eax # set IVT int 0x80
    movl %eax, 0x0200(,1) 
    movl $timer_interrupt, %eax  # set timer handler
    movl %eax, 0x0020(,1)        # timer part 1

    movb $0x36, %al     # 8293 timer setting
    movl $0x43, %edx
    outb %al, %dx
    movl $11930, %eax   # about every 1/100 second
    movl $0x40, %edx
    outb %al, %dx
    movb %ah, %al
    outb %al, %dx
    sti
    jmp .

write_char:             # set %ax, SCN_SEL,scn_pos before call               
    pushl %ebx          # put %ebx to stack
    pushw %es
    movw  SCN_SEL, %es  
    movl  scn_pos, %ebx
    cmpl  $2000, %ebx
    jb    wr1
    xor   %ebx, %ebx
wr1:  shll  $1, %ebx      # time %bx by 2
    movw  %ax, %es:(%bx)# write 2 bytes to screen, 1 character displayed
    shrl  $1, %ebx
    addl  $1, %ebx
    movl  %ebx, %cs:scn_pos
    popw  %es
    popl  %ebx          # recover %ebx from stack
    ret

system_interrupt:      #system_interrupt handler to call write_char and iret;
    push  %ds
    pushl %edx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %eax
    call  write_char
    popl  %eax
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %edx
    pop   %ds
    iret              #end of system_interrupt

timer_interrupt:
    movb  $0x20, %al
    outb  %al, $0x20
    movb  $1, %al
    cmpb  %al, %cs:current
    je    t0
    movb  $1, %cs:current
    jmp  task1
    jmp   t1
t0: movb  $0, %cs:current
    jmp  task0
t1: 
    iret

task0:
    sti
    movb $0x0A, %ah    # set the colour attributes
    movb $67, %al
    int  $0x80
    movl $0xFFF, %ecx  # pause for some time
ta2:  loop ta2
    jmp  task0

task1:
    sti
    movb $0x0D, %ah    # set the colour attributes
    movb $83, %al
    int  $0x80
    movl $0xFFF, %ecx
ta3:  loop ta3
    jmp task1

ignore_int:
    pushl %eax
    movb  $0x0E, %ah
    movb  $88, %al
    int   $0x80
    popl  %eax
    iret

setup_ivt:
    pushl %eax
    pushl %edx
    pushw %es
    movl  $0, %edx
    movl  $0, %eax
    movw  %ax, %es
    lea   ignore_int, %ax
loop_set_ivt:  
    movl  %eax, %es:(,%edx,4)
    addl  $1, %edx
    cmpl  $256, %edx
    jb    loop_set_ivt
    popw  %es
    popl  %edx
    popl  %eax
    ret

SCN_SEL:      .word 0xb800  #! memory number where colour text starts
scn_pos:      .long 0x0     # 2 bytes to save current screen postion
current:      .byte 0x1

# as boot0.s -o boot0.o;ld -o boot0 boot0.o  -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary;sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=boot0,index=0,if=floppy -cpu max


# as boot1.s -o boot1.o;ld -o boot1 boot1.o  -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary;sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=boot1,index=0,if=floppy -cpu max
```

Comment: In `ok_load` why are you copying the sectors you loaded at 0x7e0:0x0000 to 0x0000:0x0000 on top of the interrupt table? I'd say get rid of all that code that is copying and just do a FAR JMP to 0x0000:0x7e00 with `ljmp $0x0000, $0x7e00`

Comment: Thanks Michael. Reason for copying the 2nd sector to the very beginning of memory is I planed to jump to 0x0:0x0 and enter to protect mode there. Understood this rewrite the IVT area which sits in the first 1KiB of memory. Much easier to set up IDT and GDT from 0x0:0x0? Actually on weekends I already worked out to let the two tasks (processes) switch automatically to print "C"s and "S"s under protect mode. Thanks for your help, Michael.